# How come the output of this program comes to be 12?

Tags: c++, gcc

This program should calculate the square root of 169. But surprisingly the output is coming out to be 12.

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<conio.h>
    #include<math.h>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
    int i=169;
    int a=pow(i,0.5);
    cout<<a;
    getch();
    return(0);
    }
```

Comment: I get 13. Which version of gcc do you use?

Comment: probably an anomaly of floating point. define a as double and see what you get, probably 12.99999999 something.

Comment: When I use double then the answer comes out to be 13.

Comment: GCC version is 4.8.1

Answer (score 4):

Since `int a=pow(i,0.5);` is converting `pow(i,0.5);` to `int`, it only needs to be tiny fraction off from the precise value, say `12.999999999998` instead of `13` or `13.0000001`. That's because converting to `int` just chops any decimals off. There is no perfect way to solve this, but if you want to round the value to the nearest integer, try `int a = round(pow(i,0.5));`

Comment: When I use double then the answer comes to be 13. But according to your logic shouldn't it come to be 12.99999999.

Comment: Nope, you probably just didn't use enough decimal places. When printing float numbers, the output will be rounded to the number of digits you requested, which by default is 6. So `std::cout << std::setprecision(20) << something << std::endl;` should give you that sort of answer.

Comment: One more thing. Upto what precision does the function pow calculates the answer? I mean upto how many decimal places?

Comment: Should be 1ULP (so one bit wrong in the last bit), if it's done right. I can't comment as to whether it really is or not.